# How to get the id of the log when using log4net

Tags: log4net

I am using log4net and logs look like this. Pretty standard stuff.

[image]

Now I want to get the id, after I log an event, so that I may pass it on to the user of my app in case of an error.

The following always gives me null of id1 as well as id2.

```
var id1 = LogicalThreadContext.Properties["Id"];
var id2 = GlobalContext.Properties["Id"];
```

So how to get the id of a log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect this is not possible using the built-in AdoNetAppender. The instructions at https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#MS%20SQL%20Server talk about setting ID as an identity column.

That means that the ID would not be known until the record is actually written to the database and with buffering that could be long after you have logged the event.

You could create your own appender, but it might be easier just to add an extra column for your own reference and maybe set this to a new Guid before logging.